# Find all the points that lie $ 3$ units from each of the points $ (2,0,0), (0,2,0), \text{ and }(0,0,2)$

Tags: analytic-geometry, visualization

[image]

I calculated the result $$ \{(x,y,z) \in\mathbb{R^3}: x=y=z\}.$$

I'm wondering whether I did this problem correctly and if I did how to draw the set of solutions.

I used the euclidean distance formula with the square root (the euclidean norm) and set up three equations for each point $(2,0,0)$, $(0,2,0)$ and $(0,0,2)$ that made sure the distance from arbitrary $(x,y,z)$ to these three points equal to  $3$ and arrived at the solution set. –

Comment: If you show your solution and not just the final result we can inspect it to see if there are any errors.

Comment: I used the euclidean distance formula and set up three equations for each point (2,0,0), (0,2,0), and (0,0,2) that made sure the distance from arbitrary (x,y,z) = 3 and arrived at the solution set.

Comment: Certainly $(0,0,0)$ does not satisfy the requirement, so you have done something wrong.  You have the intersection of three spheres, which is a discrete set of points, not a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right: $x=y=z$.

Now, $$(x-2)^2+2x^2=9$$ or
$$3x^2-4x-5=0,$$ which gives these points.

Comment: Why don't we have to use the euclidean distance formula involving square roots? I.e. for the first point $ \sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y)^2+(z)^2} = 3$ ? and for the subsequent points  $ \sqrt{(x)^2+(y-2)^2+(z)^2} = 3$ and $ \sqrt{(x)^2+(y)^2+(z-2)^2} = 3$ if we solved this system that's how I got x=y=z which isn't a right solution.

Comment: It should be $3x^2-4x-5=0$

Comment: Huh? how did we get the equation $ (x-2)^2+2x^2=9$ ?

Comment: @Got $(x-2)^2+y^2+z^2=9$ and $x=y=z$.

Comment: @Got since $x=y=z$ we can just replace $y$ and $z$ by $x$ in the equation giving the distance from the point $(2,0,0)$

Comment: @Jihoon Kang Thank you! Today is not my day.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg no worries! We all have those days - haha it can get annoying sometimes

Answer (score 1):

The set of all points equidistqnt from $A=(2,0,0)$ and $B=(0,2,0)$:

\begin{align}
   \sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2+z^2}&=\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2+z^2} \\
   -4x+4 &= -4y+4 \\
   x&=y
\end{align}

Similarly, the set of all points equidistant from $A=(2,0,0)$ and $C=(0,0,2)$ is described by $x=z$.

Hence the set of all points equidistant from $A, B$, and $C$ is described by $x=y=z$, that is, the line P(t) = (t,t,t). If that distance is $3$, then $d(A,P(t))=3$ implies

\begin{align}
   \sqrt{(t-2)^2+t^2+t^2}&=3 \\
   3t^2-4t+4 &= 9 \\
   3t^2-4t-5 &= 0 \\
   t &= \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{19}}{3}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

To avoid forgetting solutions it is best to keep the whole system together.

$\begin{cases}
(x-2)^2+y^2+z^2=9\\
x^2+(y-2)^2+z^2=9\\
x^2+y^2+(z-2)^2=9\\
\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}
(-4x+4)+x^2+y^2+z^2=9\\
(-4y+4)+x^2+y^2+z^2=9\\
(-4z+4)+x^2+y^2+z^2=9\\
\end{cases}$

Now replacing row $(2)$ by $(2)-(1)$ you get $4x=4y$ and replacing row $(3)$ by $(3)-(1)$ you get $4x=4z$.

But you still have to carry equation $(1)$ for the system to stay complete. This is probably what you forget to do in your solution.

Or maybe you also replaced $(1)$ by a combination of rows, and lost information. In Gauss elimination at least one row should stay untouched at each step.

$\begin{cases} (-4x+4)+x^2+y^2+z^2=9\\ x=y\\ y=z\\ \end{cases} \iff 
\begin{cases} (-4x+4)+3x^2=9\\ x=y\\ y=z\\ \end{cases}\iff
\begin{cases} 3x^2-4x-5=0\\ x=y\\ y=z\\ \end{cases}$

Which solves to $\displaystyle x=y=z=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{19}}3$.